# Remove all the pattern `<<.*>>` in the text with regex

Tags: python-3.x

I have such a text

[image]

going to remove `<<.*>>` with the codes

```
#+begin_src ipython :session apue :results output
import re
fp = open("01.org", "r+")
text = fp.read()
re.sub(r"<<.*>>", "", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(text[:50])
# fp.write(text)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: ** <<page_1>>1. UNIX System Overview
:    :PROPERTIE
```

although set flags as re.multiline, the first line of `<<page_1>>` was not removed?

What's the problem with my usage?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Looks like a simple mistake - you need to assign `text = re.sub(...)` otherwise the return value is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex seems ok, you forgot to assign the new value to the text variable:

```
import re
text = "<<page_1>>1. UNIX System Overview"
text = re.sub(r"<<.*>>", "", text, flags = re.MULTILINE)
print(text[:50])
```